# `git rebase --onto --preserve-merges` reproduces the conflicts I already resolved in a merge

Tags: git, merge, rebase, git-rebase

I have a git history similar to the following that tries to keep an old feature up-to-date with master.

```
* (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) commit B'
* commit Y
* commit X
| * (HEAD -> feature) commit D
| *   commit C
| |\  
| | * commit B
| |/  
|/|   
* | commit A 
  * commit OLD
```

Master was pointing at commit A and I had to add a large fix that would have messed a lot with the old non-integrated yet feature.  I committed that fix (without worrying about the feature at first) into commit B.  I then merged master into the old feature, with many conflicts to resolve.  I commit once more in the `feature` branch, as I updated the feature a little.  Everything worked and built so I pushed commit B to master.  However (through gerrit), that commit was *rebased* over two new commits, X and Y, that were pushed meanwhile, and it give "duplicated" commit B'.

I try to rebase the merge over commit B' with command

```
git rebase --onto master B feature --preserve-merges
```

However I still have the **exact** same conflicts that I had when I did merge a with commit C.  It was quite long to do, I'm not wishing to redo the work.  What should I do so that my history looks like this ?

```
  * (HEAD -> feature) commit D'
  *   commit C'
 /|
* | (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) commit B'
* | commit Y
* | commit X
* | commit A 
  * old commit OLD
```

Thank you for any help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is natural because `git rebase` has to *copy* commits and there is no general way to copy a merge (vs the `git cherry-pick` general way to copy non-merge commits).  So a merge-preserving `git rebase` actually re-*performs* the merge.

If you can *guarantee* that the three input *trees* to the original merge—those were `B`, `OLD`, and a merge base commit we cannot see that is off the bottom of the displayed log—are the *same* as the three input trees to the new merge—these are `B'`, `OLD`, and probably the same merge base but we cannot tell for sure—then the merge *result* will be the same.

It seems likely, however, that the tree for `B'` *differs from* the tree for `B`, since `B'` has `X` and `Y` in its history as well.  Both `B'` and `B` have `A` in their histories, so if `B` is an evolution of `A`, `B'` is probably an evolution of `Y` which is probably an evolution of `X` which is probably an evolution of `A` as well, making `B'` have the changes from `X` and `Y` in it.  So the final merge result should probably *not* be the same as the original merge result.  In fact, it probably should be, more or less, "what's in C, but evolved by applying the evolutions in X and Y, as if by cherry-pick."  (This last bit is a clue to one strategy you could use here.)

The *conflicts* may well be precisely the same though, and the result of merging each *conflict* might well be exactly the same as last time.  If that's the case, `git rerere` would do just what you want.

#### There are two paths available here

We've just mentioned two things Git could do to help you here.  Both are a bit tricky, for different reasons, though.

What may be the nicest one is `git rerere`.  This *re*-use *re*corded *re*solutions thing, which is built in to Git, saves the *conflicts* when a `git merge` fails, and then as you fix up the conflicts and `git add` the resolved versions and `git commit` the result, it saves their resolutions as well.  (These two steps actually happen right after the failed merge, and during the final `git commit`.)  Then, on a subsequent `git merge`—such as the new `git merge` that `git rebase --preserve` invokes—that has conflicts, Git looks to see if those are conflicts for which it has a saved, recorded resolution.  If so, Git applies those resolutions for those conflicts, leaving only *new* conflicts to be resolved by hand.

The fly in this particular ointment is that `git rerere` *must be enabled when the conflicts occurs*, so that the conflicts get recorded, and still enabled when you add and commit the resolutions.  Obviously you did not have this turned on at that time, or you would not be asking this question. :-)

I have an idea I have never tested, but which logically should work, for handling this problem.  Or, we can use the *second* path, which I will describe now.  Then I will go back to Path 1 and describe the idea, which you can test.

#### Path 2: Using the previous result but then cherry-picking

The second path to avoid re-doing all the conflict resolutions is to grab the tree from commit `B`.  Assuming you have run `git rebase -p` and are sitting at the merge conflict right now, if you run `git status` you will see some unmerged files, and some successfully-merged files.  You need to resolve conflicts and commit—so let's resolve all the conflicts immediately by just removing every file:

```
git rm -r -- .         # assumes you are in your top level dir
```

Pretty drastic, eh? :-)  But now, without committing, let's *extract* every file in exactly the form it had in commit `C`:

```
git checkout <hash-of-C> -- .
```

Note that we still have not committed anything.  We now have the index and work-tree set up exactly the way it was in `C`.  We're missing the effects of commits `X` and `Y` though, so now let's get those added, also without committing, using `git cherry-pick -n`:

```
git cherry-pick -n <hash-of-X>
git cherry-pick -n <hash-of-Y>
```

We now have, in the index and work-tree, a tree that matches `C` except that it also has the *changes* from `X` and the *changes* from `Y` added to it.  We can `git diff HEAD` this, to make sure it looks good, and then `git commit` the result.

#### Path 1: `git rerere`

The problem with `git rerere` is that it *wasn't turned on* during the original merge, so Git did not record the conflicts and their resolutions.  But hold on a moment: above, we just saw a method by which we *re-did* a merge *exactly as before*.  All we have to do is repeat the original merge and commit its original result!

Hence, we first end the in-progress, failed merge by ending the in-progress, failing rebase:

```
git rebase --abort
```

We now have a clean index and work-tree and have not even started the rebase yet, which is fine since `git rebase -p` will repeat all this later.  We have not yet done anything requiring careful thought, we have only run a few easy Git commands.

Now we need to get onto a temporary branch whose tip commit is either of the two parents of merge commit `C`, i.e., is commit `B` or is commit `OLD`.  The easiest way to do that is:

```
git checkout feature^^
```

which gets us a detached HEAD pointing to the first parent of commit `C` (remember, `feature` points to commit `D`, so `feature^` points to commit `C`, so `feature^^` points to `C`'s first parent).  Now make sure `rerere` is enabled:

```
git config rerere.enabled true
```

and start a merge:

```
git merge feature^^2
```

Since `feature^` is commit `C` and `^2` is the second parent, this attempts to merge the other commit (if we're on `B` we merge `OLD`, if we are on `OLD` we merge `B`).  This merge fails, but since `rerere` is enabled, *this* time, Git records the conflicts.

Then, we extract the result.  We probably do not even need to `git rm -r .` (that's only if there are some files that go away during the merge), but just for the heck of it, let's use a single plumbing command that reads the index for merge `C` into our index and updates our work tree, which we could use in Path 2 as well, in place of the two-part `git rm` and `git checkout`:

```
git read-tree --reset -u feature^
```

As before, `feature^` names commit C, so we have just extracted the index for `C`.  The `--reset` part means "throw out our unmerged entries" and the `-u` part means "update the work-tree to match".

We now have the index and work-tree ready to commit, so let's make the new merge commit on the anonymous-branch detached HEAD:

```
git commit -m 'dummy merge for rerere'
```

This records our resolutions, which of course are the same resolutions we made earlier.  (Actually, we don't even need to *commit*; we can run `git rerere` and then `git merge --abort`, too.  But committing seems simpler, somehow.)

Now we throw away this merge result—we were only doing all this for `git rerere` anyway—and get back on our branch:

```
git checkout feature
```

and we are ready to repeat the preserve-merge rebase.  This time, we have `rerere` enabled, and have recorded the conflicts and their resolutions, so the automatic merge should re-use our recorded resolutions:

```
git rebase --onto master --preserve-merges B
```

and this should all just work.

#### Final thoughts: `git rererere`

If it works as advertised (I have never tested it), the six-command sequence:

```
git config rererere.enabled true
git checkout --detach <parent1>
git merge <parent2>
git read-tree --reset -u <merge>
git commit -m dummy
git checkout <where we were>
```

should probably be packaged up as a new `git rererere` command, where the new `re` stands for *repeat*. :-)  It needs just one argument, which it should verify is a merge commit.  Ideally, it should work with a temporary index and work-tree as well, so that it can be run without having to mess with any in-progress work.  As a packaged script, it probably should just run `git rerere` and then blow away the temporary index and work-tree and merge state.  If it uses the `git worktree` mechanisms to make a private `HEAD` and `MERGE_HEAD` as well, that is even better: it eliminates the need to restore `HEAD` at the end, and it won't mess with (and hence need to preserve) any existing `MERGE_HEAD`.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer !  I forgot to mention I had submodules and trying the using `git rm -r -- .` (I don't know read-tree), I created a *horde* of issues, from which I could not roll back.  For instance it suddenly said that that the `cherry-pick` head was empty and I would have to push empty commits.  I ended up using diff, as described in my own answer.

Comment: Submodules shouldn't break most of this, but they do affect a lot of things. I have not tried this particular trick with submodules and it's possible that `git rm -r` tries to remove the gitlink entry. Until it's restored, you may see other weirdness. I'd be pretty cautious around submodules (there's a reason people call them *sob*-modules... :-) ). The `git read-tree --reset -u` method should avoid these issues, but again, I have not tried it with submodules.

Comment: Now that I remember it, `git rm` plainly refused to delete the files because there was submodules, so I removed (put to the trash) **all files**, then used `git add -u`, which in retrospective, was horrendous.  But I could not roll back from it.

Comment: Well, fortunately, everything that is *committed* is easily recovered; but submodules create boundary issues (at the sub-modules) where it's hard to tell what's committed and what is not.

Comment: Even though I didn't use this in the end, I'm going to accept your answer which explains much more things than mine.

Answer (score 1):

As the available and excellent answer mentions rerere but says that the author had never used it, let me elaborate:

`git rerere` would be excellent help here if the changes leading to the eventual merge conflict were introduced rather late in the commit chain. If the conflict were to originate much earlier, it would not help much if at all.

The rerere cache works exactly like advertised: it caches the resolution of individual conflict resolutions by storing version A, B and resolved file C under their usual content hash.

The problem occurs if you rebase a long chain of commits onto something that eventually leads to a conflict when merging later on. As that "something" actually changes the files, it also changes their hashes, and thus the rerere cache knows nothing about the new hashes anymore.

So.  In short:  rerere is awesome, especially if the cache is manually shared between developers and especially if you tend to replay merges often. It works perfectly and is reasonably open to hacking around with it manually (it consists of plain files with no administrative overhead).  Rebase will lead to cache misses though, for those files changed due to the new rebase parent.

Answer (score 0):

I ended trying to replicate the patches by using git at a minimum to fix the merge, using regular patches.

I first redo the merge, without fixing anything :

```
git checkout B
git checkout -b non-merge
git merge OLD
git add -u .
git commit -m 'Temporary commit to delete'
```

I then created a patch from my fixed merge and this invalid merge

```
git diff non-merge..C > my_merge_modifs.patch
```

I want to redo the merge manually, so I reset the feature branch to its state before the merge `C`.

```
git checkout feature
git reset --hard OLD
```

I then merge with the latest commit of master, `B'` :

```
git merge master
```

I **edit the patch** and make sure to replace the correct commit hashes with a search and replace from B to B'.

I apply the patch, without using git, making sure to use option `-p1`, so that the leading `a/` and `/b` folders of git diff are skipped :

```
patch -p1 < my_merge_modifs.patch
git add -u .
git commit -m "This is commit C'"
```

Now I can rebase commit `D` onto this last commit `C'` :

```
git checkout D
git rebase C'
```

And voilà !  `master` point to `B'` and `feature` points to `D'` which is on top of commit `C'` wich merges `B'` and `OLD` rather than `B` and `OLD`.

Oh, I need to delete the merge without any conflict resolved... :

```
git branch -D non-merge
```